# responsive images resizing based on css classes

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I want to resize images basing on media queries. If this was just an image, I would attach a CSS class to the image and override it for different screen resolutions.

The thing is that the images are, actually, *fontawesome icons*. This is an example: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x
```

fa-lg, fa-2x, fa-3x, etc. are CSS classes that apply different sizes. What is the best approach to do responsive approach here - change icon sizes depending on screen size? I don't want to modify the 3rd party lib (font awesome) itself. It seems like changing screen resolution should replace one class with another...

Comment: Would js [MatchMedia](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) be an option?

Comment: @Anima-t3d do you mean sth like:
`if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  attach fa-2x class
} else {
  remove fa-2x class
}`?

Comment: Try use this font in CSS with `:before`, `content` and `font-size`.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Yes indeed, your answer is what I would have posted ;-) It seems to me the best option to be scalable later on. I also commented on your answer with a polyfill

Answer (score 1):

`fa-lg` is just the same icon as `fa-5x`, just resized. So with your media queries just resize the icon to whichever size you prefer using ordinary `font-size:` method.

I normally use `before:` with font `FontAwesome` using their unicode as seen here; http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/camera-retro/ unicode: `f083`

```
.aside .cat_title:before {
    content: "\f083";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    color: #FC0;
}

@media only screen
    and (max-width : 320px) {
    .aside .cat_title:before {
        content: "\f083";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        font-size: 10px;
        padding-right: 3px;
        color: #FC0;
    }

  }
```

then again for each media query etc.

Comment: so I would have to rewrite each icon for each screen resolution? This doesn't seem scalable...

Comment: You can put a larger font `(%, em, pt, px, etc.)` for each resolution.

Comment: @Mardzis could you give an example solution? Do you mean overwriting `.fa` class for each resolution? This would be scalable, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on @Anima-t3d's suggestion, I've made up a javascript/media-query solution that perfectly suits my needs:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)");
mql.addListener(handleResolutionChange);
handleResolutionChange(mql);

function handleResolutionChange(mql) {
  if (mql.matches) {
    $('.fa').removeClass('fa-2x');
  } else {
    $('.fa').addClass('fa-2x');
  }
}
```

There is a listener that watches screen resolution and either adds or removes CSS classes that are built into *fontawesome*. Read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Testing_media_queries

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the code above, its experimental, has very limited browser compatibility. Your best way is to use media queries with each icon using font-size imho

Comment: @mg33dev if I use 30 icons and 3 different sizes I'm not into copy-pasting or looping CSS over 90 possible combinations...